# how to save bitmap binary data to file faster using C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

At present I am using Magnification library to capture screen. once magnification callback called, I am trying to the save the bitmap data to file. But saving to bmp file is taking sometimes 60 milli sec, sometimes 130 milli seconds, So at present I am unable to get required FPS(required is 25-30 FPS but getting only 6-10 FPS).

Even I tried to store the array data to std::queue of BYTE vector. still in release mode also I am getting 6-10 FPS only as my laptop has Full HD resolution (1920 X 1080) which is nearly giving 8 MB bitmap array data.

Following is the code to save bitmap array to file.

```
void SaveBmpToFile(BITMAPINFOHEADER bmif, BYTE *pData, wstring fileName)
{
    // Setup the bitmap file header
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    LONG offBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bmif.biSize;
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42; // "BM"
    bmfh.bfOffBits = offBits;
    bmfh.bfSize = offBits + bmif.biSizeImage;
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;

    // Create the file in disk to write  
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fileName.c_str(),
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    // Return if error opening file  
    if (!hFile) return;

    DWORD dwWritten = 0;

    // Write the File header  
    WriteFile(hFile,
        &bmfh,
        sizeof(bmfh),
        &dwWritten,
        NULL);

    // Write the bitmap info header  
    WriteFile(hFile,
        &bmif,
        sizeof(bmif),
        &dwWritten,
        NULL);

    // Write the RGB Data  
    WriteFile(hFile,
        pData,
        bmif.biSizeImage,
        &dwWritten,
        NULL);

    // Close the file handle  
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

The following is how I tried to use queue to save data.

```
vector<vector<BYTE>> vecBMPData; //queue declaration

vector<BYTE> videoSample(pData, pData + bmif.biSizeImage); 
vecBMPData.push_back(videoSample);
```

Even I am trying to use named pipes but still because of saving data to file it is also causing same issue.

OS: windows 10 64-bit with Visual Studio 2010 C++.

Could you please anybody tell me how to save the bitmap array data to file faster, so I can get required FPS for screen capture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Placing the raw data into a `std::vector`, and passing it to an operating system function that writes the entire chunk, at once, is unquestionably the fastest way to accomplish the given task. If that's not enough, it's unlikely that there's any faster way. On Linux, I would trying `mmap`()ing a file, and then just copying the buffer into it.

Comment: Windows has memory-mapped files, too. Use the `MapViewOfFile` API. It is unlikely that this will be significantly faster than writing the data out to a file using `WriteFile`, however. Do consider concatenating the data and making only a single call to `WriteFile` to avoid the overhead of multiple system calls.

Comment: Undoubtedly, writing to disk is your bottleneck. Since you cannot improve writing speed (beyond minimizing system calls/write chunks), you'll have to reduce the payload. Right now you are writing uncompressed data. Try to see if compression helps to improve performance. If it doesn't, you'll have to speed up the hardware (RAID systems, SSDs, etc.).

Comment: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) provides encoders you can use. For regular desktop screenshots, the [PNG format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430028.aspx) is usually a good choice for lossless compression.